# CKEditor - attach to AJAX loaded content

Tags: ajax, jquery, ckeditor

I have page that has a `contenteditable` area that has a CKEDitor attached.

what I'm looking to do, is to load another page to replace the current one, that loads in another `contenteditable` div via AJAX

This works fine, but the loaded content, doesn't have the CKEditor WYSIWYG attached.

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="content"></div>

 $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",                                    
  url: 'load.php',
  data: "id="+id,                        

  success: function(data)          
  {
     // I've tried using the CKEditor config, but doesn't load
  } 
});
```

load.php

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For dynamically added elements you need to call `CKEDITOR.inline`. This method accepts  an element (or its id) on which editor should be initialized and config object. See [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline).

[added] 
*your dynamically created div or text area*

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="content">...</div>
```

*end your js with this code to attach ckeditor*

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'content' );
```

Comment: Thank you for this - exactly what I was looking for when adding ckeditor instances dynamically via ajax.